# How can I use a CSL format in Overleaf or convert it to a BST?

Tags: natbib, overleaf, bibliographystyle, bst, csl

I want to use the following CSL file from the Zotero style repository (also available on Mendelay) in Overleaf: https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=movement%20ecology

All the questions I could find say that there is no easy way to use a CSL files in Latex because they use completely different formats (XML-based vs biblatex).

Alternatively, are there repositories of BST files?

It seems impossible to me that most citation style formats are written in CSL, but there is no way to simply use them in Latex/Overleaf or convert them to BST.

Edit: I tried using the [citation-style-language](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citation-style-language) package on CTAN by including all of the downloaded content in the root directory of the following Tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{citation-style-language}
\cslsetup{style = movement-ecology}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith2020}  

\parencite{Smith2020}  

\textxite{Smith2020}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the following entry in example.bib

```
@article{Smith2020,
    title = {Example title},
    year = {2020},
    journal = {Ecology},
    author = {Smith, T and Leu, S and Bull, T},
    pages = {1--10},
    volume = {15}
}
```

However, this produces a number of errors:
[image]

and fails to generate any in text citations or bibliography:
[image]

Comment: Maybe try [`citation-style-language`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citation-style-language)?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working in Overleaf. 
Here's the Overleaf file: https://www.overleaf.com/7364178849rhytyhmrqbvv
I'm getting several errors

Comment: For future record, here's zip of Overleaf directory: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVDgYQMqc14o_Sz2qK1W6ceX70F48l2i/view?usp=sharing
and errors: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15YYmHqRu4--7tcQl0bSKakhTkP-et14B/view?usp=sharing

Comment: don't link to some overleaf project or other external sites, such links will dead at some time. Add a small but complete example here.

Comment: Added reproducible example.

Comment: This package requires loads  `biblatex` and so `\citep` and `\citet` aren’t defined hence the errors. Try using `\parencite` and `\textxite` respectively.

Comment: You are correct @AlanMunn, citation-style-language is incompatible with biblatex and natbib. I have replaced \citep and \citet as suggested (updated in OP), but still receive the same errors/warnings.

Comment: Have you tried it with a CSL-JSON file instead of a bib file? My guess though is that there's no easy way in Overleaf to invoke citeproc-lua. You might try it with a local TeX distribution just to see if the files work, and then contact Overleaf about supporting citeproc.

Comment: Actually, the package is not using `biblatex`, but uses some command names that are also found in `biblatex`. It  defines only a single `\cite` command, so my earlier comment isn't applicable. It also requires LuaLaTeX to run, but I can't get s simple example to work on my machine, so I'm not sure this is the best route to use.

Comment: This is now possible: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-2023-now-available#citation-style-language-using-csl-stylesheets-for-citations-and-references

Answer (score 4):

Update 2022-09-30:

I've added narrative citation commands `\textcite` and `\citet` in [c23c66f](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/commit/c23c66ff674c405453b8f7fe3c521b13d29470bd) and I'll publish it to CTAN soon.

---

I'm the author of the `citeproc-lua` engine `citation-style-language` package and thanks for you feedback!

Technically, it's impossible to convert a CSL style a BibTeX style (bst). The bst language is very simple and it lacks data structures like list or map. I can hardly imagine implementing the CSL features with this language. Besides, its postfix grammar is not easy to write.

As for the provided LaTeX document, the current version (0.2.2) of `citation-style-language` package only provides `\cite`, `\cites`, and `\nocite` and such commands as `\citep`, `\citet`, `\parencite`, and `\textcite` are not available at the moment. They are more complex from the CSL's perspective and they require supports from the Lua engine. I'm currently working on those feaures (see the [`text-cite`](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/commits/text-cite%3E) branch of the GitHub repository). They are about to be available in the next month.

Another issue in your provided example is that `movement-ecology` is a "dependent" (CSL terminology) style (https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/dependent/movement-ecology.csl) and its "independent-parent" is `springer-vancouver-brackets`. Since the `citation-style-language` package does not support dependent styles at the moment, you need to acquire the `springer-vancouver-brackets.csl` from the CSL styles repository and change the style setting to `\cslsetup{style = springer-vancouver-brackets}`.
Perhaps I should redistribute all of the CSL styles along with the LaTeX package. This worth further discussion.

After these modifications, the following code produces the PDF.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{citation-style-language}
\cslsetup{style = springer-vancouver-brackets}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith2020}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

As stated in the documentation, this package is in early development stage and there are limitations. Bug reports, features and other discussions are welcome at the repository issue tracker (https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues).